# How to fix Python 2.7 MySQL 5.7 connection issue?

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.7

I'm working with an Ubuntu (Linode) 16.04 LTS / nginx / uwsgi / Python-2.7 / Django / MySQL 5.7 application.

A little more than a month ago the box was dist upgraded from 14.04 LTS, and at that time or soon after that MySQL was upgraded from 5.5 to 5.7. We had to recreate the Python virtual environment, and then things worked fine. Up until today when Linode Fremont experienced issues, and the box was restarted. Since that restart we are experiencing undeterministic MySQL restarts.

One suspicion is a possible file system corruption in case the restart was preceded by a "pull the plug out" type power down (the report contains the keyword power failure). I restarted again the box forcing `fsck`, and I still won't rule that out completely, but I rather seek for software issues.

The `MySQL` logs don't contain any suspicious. The `uwsgi` logs however show:

```
...The work of process 27651 is done. Seeya!                                                                                                                                                  
worker 1 killed successfully (pid: 27651)                                                                                                                                                     
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 27686)                                                                                                                                                     
Fri Feb 23 18:33:38 2018 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) !!!                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__                                                        
    self.load_middleware()                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 52, in load_middleware                                                  
    mw_instance = mw_class()                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/opt/webapps/company/webapp/djangoapp/middleware.py", line 30, in __init__                                                                                             
    self.group = UserGroup.objects.get(name="********** - Read Only")                                                                                                                     
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method                                                   
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 328, in get                                                                
    num = len(clone)                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in __len__                                                            
    self._fetch_all()                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all                                                         
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())                                                                                                                                                
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator                                                           
    results = compiler.execute_sql()                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql                                                 
    cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute                                                           
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                               
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute                                                           
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__                                                                   
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)                                                                                                                                         
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute                                                           
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute                                                     
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute                                                                   
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/opt/webapps/.virtualenvs/company/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler                                                    
    raise errorclass, errorvalue                                                                                                                                                              
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

The interesting thing is that this doesn't happen all the time. It's non deterministic. The connection of Python/Django to MySQL is provided by the `MySQL-python==1.2.5` `pip` package (at least AFAIK, that package is installed). https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5 does not list MySQL 5.7 as compatible "MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported." (that's also `MySQLdb` on the above call stack). **Which Python 2.7 package should I use to connect to an 5.7 MySQL?**

On my local development environment (17.10 Ubuntu) I also use MySQL 5.7.21 just like the Linode box, but everything works stable. However the dev server is not an nginx/uwsgi setup.

---

We managed to stabilize the situation by artificially delaying DB calls, but that's super hacky and not good for performance. We need a proper solution.

Comment: Research seems to point to a configuration that may have been overridden; `max_allowed_packets` in the mysql conf file. This would be consistent with your observations regardig delaying DB calls and could seem nondeterministic based on current load. A few other anecdotes point to memory issues. Have you checked your mysql configuration configuration and available memory?

Comment: Oh, the good old `max_allowed_packets`. I thought I was tuning that because importing a mysqldump was puking. I have to revisit that.